# Can i Make a contact form like in the website page "http://aitatennis.com/raking.php", in wordpress plugin contact form 7?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form, contact-form-7

[First demo](http://aitatennis.com/raking.php)

Can i Make a contact form like [first demo](http://aitatennis.com/raking.php)  website page, in wordpress plugin contact form 7?
and [one more example](http://www.infotuts.com/demo/cascaded-drop-down-jquery-php/) link is
[Second demo](http://www.infotuts.com/demo/cascaded-drop-down-jquery-php/)

Answer (score 0):

you can create these contact form simple with j query  html and css

Comment: I am developing a wordpress site. So how can i use j query html and css in that?

Comment: create a template in your theme and you can do this

Comment: ok i added new template in my site... Then what should i do..?

Comment: then do your code with j query css and html its eassy

Comment: ok any problem you can comment here and dont forget accept my answer :)